# verify CORBA SSL communication

Tags: ssl, corba, jacorb

I have two processes communicating with each other using IIOP over SSL (with JacORB). How do I verify that the message packets are actually encrypted?

Answer (score 1):

You can use wireshark to record and view all traffic and inspect the packets on the network.